# Xamarin Firebase com.google.gms:google-services not applied to gradle project

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, gradle

I recently updated my copy of Visual Studio and am now encountering errors related to this Firebase/gradle `com.google.gms:google-services` in my Xamarin Forms project. I have not heard of any of these things before and do not see any related files or any code with those names.

Here is the full error:

`[FirebaseApp] Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.` 
`[FirebaseInitProvider] FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful`

Based on what I have read in other threads Xamarin doesn't support gradle as it is meant for Android only and it must be handled through some third-party manner. I tried installing the NuGet package but that did nothing so I have uninstalled it as it was never being used before.

At first I was able to temporarily fix this by updating my copy of Visual Studio for Mac and I assumed it was just some weird issue from the previously, larger update. However, once again I am encountering this issue and this time after more updates the issue remains so I am unsure of what to try next because like I said I never added anything related to Firebase/gradle and was not getting any errors for months until these past few updates.

Other threads I have read involve editing code related to the `com.google.gms:google-services` version but like I said there has never been any references to this google service so I am hesitant to start manually adding things blindly.

Update: I once again uninstalled using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall?view=vsmac-2022#visual-studio-for-mac-and-xamarin-script) script and reinstalled Visual Studio for Mac. It works for a few hours of use and then gives the same error. No indication of anything changing, I am very confused.

Comment: Did you find a fix? What version of `Xamarin.Firebase.Database` were you using?

Comment: No I haven't found any permanent fix yet. For months I was able to resolve it using some combo of factory resetting the emulator, starting the emulator through the device manager, restarting Visual Studio, and restarting my computer. I am actually just today getting what I think is the same issue but now without any specific error message, it just appears that the app won't start. I also do not have `Xamarin.Firebase.Database` installed at all

Comment: Oh I forgot the temp fix that usually works best when all else fails. Try re-cloning the repository, somehow that works best.

Comment: I found that this solution worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77281589/811058