# Firebase Messaging is not working in .NET Android

Tags: android, .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have recently migrated my app from Xamarin.Android where Firebase Messaging was working fine.
Now I am not getting the token, and this message appears in the output window:

[FirebaseApp] Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
[FirebaseInitProvider] FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

I have called FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this); in my application's OnCreate method, and the AndroidManifest contains these lines within the <application tag:

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

google-services.json is added to the project, with the correct API key, and I have implemented the FirebaseMessagingService class:

```
[Service(Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override async void OnNewToken(string p0)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnNewToken");
        base.OnNewToken(p0);
        ...
    }

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnMessageReceived");
        ...
    }   
}
```

I am using the latest Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging NuGet package, which is 123.1.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the build action for google-services.json to @(GoogleServicesJson) solved the problem.